# Attach button to panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a simple Winform application with a panel and a button on it. when move panel, the button doesn't. Is it possible to attach button to panel so each operation on panel implies operation on button too?

Comment: Hi and welcome. We need more information and preferably code. "when move panel" what does that mean? did you implement drag and drop? how do you intend to move the panel control on your form?

Comment: I have a form and a Panel control onto it. I solved using property Parent of Panel control.
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myPanel.Parent= this;
                   ...
But now, at runtime, if I resize form, panel doesn't according to it.

Comment: You are doing something we can't see.  Post minimal code that reproduces the problem and edit your post with that information.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to go to the panel's properties page, find the property “dock” and set it to the option that best suits your needs, probably “fill”. Whatever you do to the panel, will also manage changes to controls docked to the panel.